# Jenkins master and agent cluster AWS CLI

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, aws-cli

I'm wondering how could I use AWS CLI on a Jenkins master and agent cluster installed in a kubernetes cluster.

Is there any pluging to get aws cli? I have pipeliens which use aws client in Jenkinsfile so I am not able to run any build as the aws client is not installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any special plugin for that. You may just install `aws-cli` on a node as a build stage.

All you need is Python installed on agent. You create `virtualenv` and install `aws-cli` in it. You can also provide credentials using [`withCredentials`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/#-withcredentials-bind-credentials-to-variables) step. Then, you just use this `aws-cli` installed in `virtualenv`.